# Asterisk не показывает номера при выводе на web-страницу

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, asterisk

Есть скрипт, который оценивает работу специалистов компании посредством обзвона клиентов. Клиент жмёт любую кнопку от 1 до 5 (оценка) и данная цифра вместе с номером абонента сохраняется в *mysql*.

Как вывести эти данные на web-страницу?

У меня выводится оценка, а номер абонента нет. Вместо него пустая строка.
Подскажите, как быть.

Вот как у меня всё организовано в `extesions.conf`:

> (Если абонент нажал цифру "3")
>
> exten => 3,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO `asterisk`.`opinion` (`id`, `callerid`, `exten`, `queues`, `opinion`)  VALUES (NULL, '${FROMEXTEN}', '${CDR(dst)}', '${DIALEDNUM}', 3))

номер абонента добавляется в столбец `callerid` таблицы `opinion` благодаря конструкции `${FROMEXTEN}`.

По факту, номер правда добавляется, но в виде пустой строки.

Comment: а в базе данных номер есть? тогда смотрите на код, формирующий эту веб-страницу.

Comment: вот именно, что в базе он тоже в виде просто пустой строки =( Простите, сразу об этом не написала. Как добавить номер в базу в виде именно номера, а не пустой строки? Что я конкретно сделала не так?

Comment: значит, `${FROMEXTEN}` не содержит этого номера. да, собственно, из самого названия следует, что это про `extension`, а не про внешний номер.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: ну, из [списка](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List), судя по названию, ближе всего — это `${DIALEDPEERNUMBER}` (предупреждаю — я в астериске разбираюсь весьма поверхностно).

Comment: а в столбец `queues` что у вас попадает? судя по *sql-запросу* — это содержимое переменной `${DIALEDNUM}`. может быть, оно и содержит набранный номер?

Comment: Вставила ${DIALEDPEERNUMBER} вместо ${FROMEXTEN}. Не помогло ((

Comment: queues содержит добавочный номер. Но не внешний, который как раз нужен

Comment: *Не помогло* — слишком мало информации. что попало в столбец `callerid`? пустая строка? попробуйте «научным тыком» другие связанные по смыслу переменные из приведённого выше [*списка*](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List). `${DIALEDPEERNAME}`, `${CALLERIDNAME}`,`${CALLERID(name)}`,` ${CALLERID(num)}` и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: exten => 5267,n,WaitExten(10)exten => 1,1,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost *** *** ***)
exten => 1,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO `asterisk`.`opinion` (`id`, `callerid`, `exten`, `queues`, `opinion`)  VALUES (NULL, '${CALLERID(num)', '${CDR(dst)}', '${CALLERID(num)', 1))
exten => 1,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})
Это кусок из extensions.conf. Добавочный номер 5267. И этот самый добавочный номер попадает в queues. в id понятно, попадает порядковый номер. в callerid пустая строка, в exten оценка, такая же, как и в opinion.

Comment: ну, если в `${CALLERID(num)` содержится вызывающий *extension*, значит всё логично — соответствует названиям. остаются (исхожу только из названий): `${DIALEDPEERNAME}` и `${DIALEDPEERNUMBER}`. если ни одна из них не содержит набранный номер, то, боюсь, больше подсказать ничего не смогу. подозреваю, что здесь вы очень не скоро встретите знатоков астериска и вам лучше бы в какой-нибудь специализированный форум обратиться.

Comment: ага! оказывается, `${DIALEDPEERNAME}` и `${DIALEDPEERNUMBER}` поломаны. [*предлагают*](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DIALEDPEERNUMBER) какой-то обходной путь, смысл которого я, увы, не улавливаю. кстати, есть ещё что-то, вроде бы, подходящее: [`${CALLERID(dnid)}` — dialed number (digits only in the POTS/ISDN world)](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+callerid)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за то, что помогаете. Я вот поняла, что мой EXTEN при добавлении данных в mysql содержит оценку, а не номер. Тогда по идее внешний номер, на который я звоню, надо объявить ранее до соединения с базой и задать как глобальную переменную. Я знаю, что это делается через Set, а как правильно это оформить, не пойму. Просто тогда вместо FROMEXTEN я бы вставила глобальную переменную внешнего номера, на который я звоню и по идее всё бы работало

Comment: нет, это для меня высшая математика — я далёк от астерисковских «потрохов».

Comment: Всё равно я вам благодарна. Спасибо ещё раз =)